# Iterate through table rows and print a href text with Python Selenium

Tags: python, loops, selenium

My overall goal is to iterate through every tr in this table and go through several `td`'s per `tr` and print out the text in them.

I've tried going back as far as the body yet still no luck. ideally I would like to just run a `for`loop through `table[@id='aui']/tbody/tr[i]/td[i]` where `i` is the variable in the range(0, sizeOfTable)

```
ele = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='page']/section[@id='content']/div[@class='aui-page-panel']/div[@class='aui-page-panel-inner']/section[@class='aui-page-panel-content']/div[@class='aui-page-panel']/div[@class='aui-page-panel-inner']/section[@class='aui-page-panel-content']/div[@class='module']/div[@id='projects']/div[@class='p-list']/table[@id='aui']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")
```

right now when I run `print(ele.text)` after creating `ele`, it just prints out an empty list

[image: this is the html I'm working off of:]

Comment: Please paste code as text here, you can format it with the `{}` button, don't paste pure text content as picture here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for the issue is a wrong XPath. The table has `class` with `aui` but not `id`.

Correct the XPath as below.

```
  //table[@class='aui']//tr
```

This should give you a list of rows and then you can iterate through them.

**Script:** if you want to print the text in the cell then use this.

```
rows = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.auti  tr")
for row in rows:
    # get the hrefs
    columsWithLink = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[a]")
    for column in columsWithLink:
        # print column text
        print (column.text)
        # print link href
        print(column.find_element_by_xpath(".//a").get_attribute("href"))
```

**Script:** if you just want to print link hrefs then use the below

```
rows = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.auti  tr")
for row in rows:
    # get the hrefs
    links = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td/a")
    for link in links:
        # print link href
        print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: so im trying to print out the highlighted text in the html: ".com Ownership support", but in your code you jump from table to tr, dont i have to include the tbody?

Comment: Not required when you are dealing with css.

Comment: If you are trying to get the text associated with link, then try `column.find_element_by_xpath(".//a").text` and `link.text` respectively in the above answer.

Comment: i got the text thank you! would you happen to know how to work off using a html doc instead of a url link as a webdriver? i have to log in each time to test the site so i want to skip it all

Comment: Cool. If you want to load the local html doc then you can use `url = r"file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/sample.html"` and then `driver.get(url)` should load the local page.

Comment: Dont' forget about `file:///` at the beginning of the file path.

Comment: if the python file and html file are in the same directory, do still need to specify the whole path or can i just do file:///sample.html?

Comment: you have to provide the entire path as url. Please accept the answer if you feel the issue is resolved.